# sending a map as parameter in onclick function inside a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

For reasons... in our project we redraw the page whenever we search a list of data. When we click on the fourth column in a row of the table, the data in the row needs to show up on the new modal/popup. I am trying to send the data shown on the row to the modal window by saving each variables in a map. However, the onclick function does not seem to recognize this and devtools returns a unexpected identifier syntax error.

Here is an example of what I was doing...

on my jsp file...

```
<script>
// After receiving name, userId, userNumber by Ajax,    

let thisMap = new Map();
thisMap.set("NAME", name);
thisMap.set("USERID", userId);
thisMap.set("PHONE", userNumber);

let insertTable = "<tbody>"
insertTable += "<td><div class='tIn'>"+name+"</div></td>";
insertTable += "<td><div class='tIn'>"+userId+"</div></td>";
insertTable += "<td><div class='tIn'>"+userPhone+"</div></td>";
insertTable += "<td><div class='tIn' id='openDetail'>";
insertTable += "<a style='cursor: pointer;'onclick='openModal("+thisMap+");'>";

$("#thisTable").html(insertTable);

function openModal(mapData){
   $("#userNameHere").val(mapData.get('USERNAME'));
   $("#userIdHere").val(mapData.get('USERID'));
   $("#userPhoneHere").val(mapData.get('PHONE'));
   
   showModal("thisModal"); // lets say this is a function the shows the below hidden modal
}
</script>

<body>
   // LIST TABLE
   <div id="thisTable" class="thisTable">

   // MODAL
   <div class="modal-container" id="requestDetail">
   <div class="modal-wrapper">
   <div class="contentsArea">
       <ul>
           <li>
                <div>
                     <span>THIS NAME</span>
                     <div class="input">
                        <input type="text" id="userNameHere">
                     </div>
                </div>
           </li>
           <li>
                <div>
                     <span>THIS NAME</span>
                     <div class="input">
                        <input type="text" id="userIdHere">
                     </div>
                </div>
           </li>
              <li>
                <div>
                     <span>THIS NAME</span>
                     <div class="input">
                        <input type="text" id="userPhoneHere">
                     </div>
                </div>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div> 
</body>
```

Do onclick inside tags not support sending map objects? Or am I missing something? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really see the point of using a `Map` in the situation you have here. The following would be my way of

- putting information from an AJAX call into a table and
- making it editable in a modal

Obviously, this can only be part of the complete functionality. But maybe it gives you some ideas of how to proceed?

```js
const data=[{name:"Harry Potter",userId:"potterh",userNumber:"+999-123456"},
            {name:"Ron Weasley",userId:"weasleyr",userNumber:"+999-456123"},
            {name:"Hermiony Granger",userId:"grangerh",userNumber:"+999-112233"}];

const tb=document.querySelector("#thisTable tbody"),
      md=document.querySelector("#requestDetail"), inps=md.querySelectorAll("input");
md.style.display="none";

tb.innerHTML=
      data.map(function(d){return"<tr><td>"+Object.values(d).join("</td><td>")
                                +"</td><td title=\"edit\" class=\"edit\">✎</td></tr>"})
          .join("\n");
tb.onclick=function(ev,e,tr){e=ev.target
 if (e.classList.contains("edit")) {
  md.style.display="";
  [].slice.call(e.closest("tr").children,0).forEach(
    function(c,i){inps[i]&&(inps[i].value=c.textContent)}  )
  
}}
```

```css
#requestDetail {position:absolute; top:0px; left:300px}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #ddd}
#thisTable tr td:nth-child(4) {cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<!-- LIST TABLE -->
<table id="thisTable">
<thead><th>Name</th><th>UserId</th><th>Phone</th></thead><tbody></tbody>
</table>

<!-- MODAL --><th></th></thead><tbody></tbody>
<div class="modal-container" id="requestDetail">
  <div class="modal-wrapper">
    <div class="contentsArea">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>
            <span>Username</span>
            <div class="input">
              <input type="text" id="name">
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <span>User-Id</span>
            <div class="input">
              <input type="text" id="userId">
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <span>Phone</span>
            <div class="input">
              <input type="text" id="userNumber">
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And although I have always been an outspoken fan of jQuery, there is no reason to use it in this case, as long as you are dealing with "modern browsers" ...

**Further explanation:**
@Akxe: I did indeed use the following "monstrosity":

```
tb.onclick=function(ev,e,tr){e=ev.target
 if (e.classList.contains("edit")) { ... }}
```

This is a *delegated* click event, assigned to the `tbody` element. You are certainly right, that the direct assignment of event-listeners using

```
tb.querySelectorAll('td.edit').forEach(function(e){e.addEventListener(...)})
```

is slightly shorter and maybe "prettier"! But it will not work on possible "new arrivals" in the table (assuming that it *might* get updated). If, on the other hand, the table is intended to be "static", then there is *no reason for my delegated approach* and I will continue to eat my humble pie. ;-)

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer! I will look more into this... We are dealing with IE, chrome, edge, etc... and in IE arrow functions don't seem to work!

Comment: OK, that is a fair point! Obviously, the arrow functions can easily be re-written as `function(){...}`s and the spread operator `[...collection]` is now replaced by `[].slice.call(collection)`. This should now at least work on IE 10 and 11.

Comment: Please use `tb.querySelectorAll('td.edit').addEventLisener(...)` instead of that unreadable monstrosity

Comment: Thank you both for your comments! Although the posted example is a simplified version of what we are actually doing, all your answers helped greatly!

Answer (score 0):

This is the only an edited answer of @carsten, but I felt like the javascript needed to be more readable for a newcomer.

---

You don't need `Map`, prefer `{}` for simplicity and readability. `Map`s are used if you want objects as keys.

The main error was, that you printed converted the `thisMap` to a string and passed that string to the function. If you were to look at the HTML you would see `<a style='cursor: pointer;'onclick='openModal([Object object]);'>`.

Also, only `tr` is a valid child of `tbody` and `tr` can only have `th` or `td`.

```js
const tableBody = document.querySelector("#thisTable tbody");
const modal = document.querySelector("#requestDetail");
const inputs = {
  name: document.querySelector('#name'),
  userId: document.querySelector('#userId'),
  userNumber: document.querySelector('#userNumber'),
};

function appendRows(rows) {
  rows.forEach(row => {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    
    const name = document.createElement('td');
    name.textContent = row.name;
    tr.appendChild(name);
    
    const userId = document.createElement('td');
    userId.textContent = row.userId;
    tr.appendChild(userId);
    
    const userNumber = document.createElement('td');
    userNumber.textContent = row.userNumber;
    tr.appendChild(userNumber);
    
    const edit = document.createElement('td');
    edit.title = 'edit';
    edit.className = 'edit';
    edit.textContent = '✎';
    edit.addEventListener('click', () => openModal(row));
    tr.appendChild(edit);
    
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
  });
}

function openModal(obj) {
  inputs.name.value = obj.name;
  inputs.userId.value = obj.userId;
  inputs.userNumber.value = obj.userNumber;
  
  modal.style.display = '';
}

appendRows([
  {name:"Harry Potter",userId:"potterh",userNumber:"+999-123456"},
  {name:"Ron Weasley",userId:"weasleyr",userNumber:"+999-456123"},
  {name:"Hermiony Granger",userId:"grangerh",userNumber:"+999-112233"},
]);
```

```css
#requestDetail {position:absolute; top:0px; left:300px}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #ddd}
#thisTable tr td:nth-child(4) {cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<!-- LIST TABLE -->
<table id="thisTable">
<thead>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>UserId</th>
  <th>Phone</th>
  <th><!-- edit button --></th>
</thead>
<tbody><!-- generated --></tbody>
</table>

<!-- MODAL --><th></th></thead><tbody></tbody>
<div class="modal-container" id="requestDetail" style="display: none">
  <div class="modal-wrapper">
    <div class="contentsArea">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>
            <span>Username</span>
            <div class="input">
              <input type="text" id="name">
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <span>User-Id</span>
            <div class="input">
              <input type="text" id="userId">
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <span>Phone</span>
            <div class="input">
              <input type="text" id="userNumber">
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```